# Getting a list of projects from ArcGIS Image Service REST end point

Tags: python, arcgis-rest-api, image-service

I've made a script to get a list of projects from a ArcGIS REST end point, it works maybe 75% of the time but seems to suffer from time outs, possibly from making too many requests to the server?

I'm a bit ignorant on the server-side of things, but just wanted to see if I could make my code more efficient / make less requests as a workaround? I make go to the json for each individual project as a workaround so I'm wondering if there is a better approach for this step.

When it does fail, the error looks like below - because I assume the script can't reach the response json:

```
File "/home/script.py", line 82, in main
    if 'Name' in response_json['attributes']:
KeyError: 'attributes'
```

Code snippet below:

```
#construct URL with query 
service_type = 'Foo'
service_name = 'Bar'

prefix = f'https://my-domain.com/'
service = f'arcgis/rest/services/{service_type}/{service_name}/ImageServer/'
query = 'query?where=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=false&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=true&returnCountOnly=false&pixelSize=&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnDistinctValues=false&multidimensionalDefinition=&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&f=html'
token = '11111'

url_query = prefix + service + query + token

#Lists to populate
object_ids = []
projects = []

#Read rest end point using constructed URL
parser = 'html.parser'
page = urlopen(url_query)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,parser,from_encoding=page.info().get_param('charset'))

#Get object id links and append to object list
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True, text=re.compile('^[0-9]+$')):
    object_ids.append(link['href'])

#count
project_count = 0

#Iterate through object id list, construct a url and append names to project list
for x in object_ids:
    url = prefix + str(x) + '?f=pjson' + token

    response_json = json.load(urlopen(url))

    projects.append(response_json['attributes']['Name'])
    print(response_json['attributes']['Name'])
```

Comment: The HTML format for ArcGIS REST API is really meant for human consumption, I suggest working solely with JSON format for scripting and/or processing the information returned from ArcGIS REST API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rethinking my entire approach landed me here - it works much better and reduces the amount of calls to the endpoint, resulting in hardly any timeouts. Credit to Ablajan Sulaiman for this [method to bypassing the query limit](https://toarches.medium.com/easy-way-to-bypass-rest-api-request-limits-2dc9afc0f027) which helped a lot.

My code:

```
        import requests
        import csv
        import os
        import datetime
        import click
        
        #construct URL 
        service_type = 'Foo'
        service_name = 'Bar'
        
        prefix = f'https://my-domain.com/'
        service = f'arcgis/rest/services/{service_type}/{service_name}/ImageServer/'
        token = '11111'
    
        #case handling for name field
        
        url = prefix + service + "?f=pjson" + token
    
        fields_json = requests.get(url).json()
        fields = fields_json['fields']
    
        name_field = f['name']
    
        # Get object ids of features
        where = "1=1"
        obj_query = f"query?where={where}&returnIdsOnly=true&f=json"
    

        urlstring = prefix + service + obj_query + token
        
        #identify number of records
        response = requests.get(urlstring)
        js = response.json()
        idfield = js["objectIdFieldName"]
        idlist = js["objectIds"]
        idlist.sort()
        numrec = len(idlist)
        print(f"\nNumber of target records: {numrec}")
    
        # Gather features
        print("\nGathering records...")
        for i in range(0, numrec, maxrc):
            torec = i + (maxrc - 1)
            if torec > numrec:
                torec = numrec - 1
            fromid = idlist[i]
            toid = idlist[torec]
            where = f"{idfield} >= {fromid} and {idfield} <= {toid}"
            query = f"query?where={where}&returnGeometry=false&outFields={name_field}&f=json"
            print(f"  {where}")
    
            
            url_query = prefix + service + query + token
    
            response_json = requests.get(url_query).json()
            features = response_json['features']
    
            for f in features:
                name = f['attributes'][name_field]
                projects.append(name)
    
            projects.sort()
    
            # Timestamp
        def timeStamped(fname, fmt='{fname}_%Y-%m-%d'):
            return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)
    
            #Add records to CSV
        with open((timeStamped(os.path.join(outpath, service_name)) + ".csv"), 'w', newline="") as file:
            wr = csv.writer(file)
            for project in projects:
                project_count += 1
                wr.writerow([project])
```